# switch bg image if case

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following bbcode:

```
<style type="text/css">
#k-r {font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: 1px 1px #fcfcfc;}
.k-number {display:table-cell; background-image: url('/images/super1.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; height:30px; width:30px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;}
</style>
<div id="k-r">
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER1}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER2}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER3}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER4}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER5}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER6}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER5}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER7}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER8}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER9}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER10}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER11}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER12}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER13}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER14}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER15}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER16}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER17}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER18}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER19}</div>
<div class="k-number">{NUMBER20}</div>
</div>
```

And I need the following:

```
if {NUMBERN} <= 10, then background-image: url('/images/super1.png');
if {NUMBERN} > 10 <20, then background-image: url('/images/super2.png');
if {NUMBERN} >= 20 <30, then background-image: url('/images/super3.png');
if {NUMBERN} >= 30 <40, then background-image: url('/images/super4.png');
if {NUMBERN} >= 40 <50, then background-image: url('/images/super5.png');
if {NUMBERN} >= 50 <60, then background-image: url('/images/super6.png');
if {NUMBERN} >= 60 <70, then background-image: url('/images/super7.png');
if {NUMBERN} >= 70, then background-image: url('/images/super10.png');
```

Well I know how to make it work using php's switch, but I can't make it work using JS. I tried different codes but none of them works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS3 feature `nth-child` you can apply the `background-image` for your number ranges. Look at my example in the below jsfiddle. In my case, I have just changed the `background-color` based on the number count of `div`. Instead of color you can apply your `background-image`.

```
#k-r div.k-number:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+10){background-color:green;}
#k-r div.k-number:nth-child(n+11):nth-child(-n+19){background-color:yellow;}
#k-r div.k-number:nth-child(n+20):nth-child(-n+29){background-color:orange;}
#k-r div.k-number:nth-child(n+30):nth-child(-n+39){background-color:blue;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m7xx96k6/1/)

Comment: thanks! but there's allways only 20 {NUMBERN} which means there's only 20 numbers. Any of these 20 NUMBERN could be beetween 1 to 100

Comment: oh ok. I misunderstand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/hdr1mysa/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.k-number').each(function() {
        var value = parseInt($(this).html());
        if(value > 10) {
           $(this).css('background-color', 'green'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Once the document is fully loaded, it iterates through every item with the class `k-number` and parses its content as an integer. If the value is bigger than 10, the background color is changed.

You should be able to adopt this solution to your problem by adding more conditions and changing the background image instead of the color.